How to add a tag to a selected text and close/open the parent before/after
trying to create a Richt Texteditor in Javascript. I have a Tag
<span class="text-3xl">Foo</span>

and want to edit it to something like
<span class="text-3xl">F</span><span class="text-sm">o</span><span class="text-3xl">o</span>

My first attempt works, for inserting a Tag inside the other
<span class="text-3xl">F<span class="text-sm">o</span>o</span>

using this code:
var spanElement= document.createElement("span");
spanElement.className = size;
var selection= window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
var selectedText = selection.extractContents();
elem.appendChild(selectedText);
selection.insertNode(elem);

but need some help with closing/reopening the tag before/after the inner tag.

This question is similar to: How do I wrap a text selection from window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0) with an html tag?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I'm not sure what you're creating is explained in details. Why would a rich text editor handle classes like text-3xl *sm etc, and what technologies are you using to do it and what's the purpose of it. Contenteditable? Otherwise it's just pure asking how to wrap characters into SPAN elements. Also what's the logic behind the order of classes applied? Your "something like:" is really confusing.

After reading some other threads, espacially Javascript: I can get the text of a selection, now how do I get the text outside the selection?
is my temp solution


function replaceOriginal(size) {
    var selection= window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    var tagText = getOuterRange(findSelection());
    var parentNode =window.getSelection().focusNode.parentNode;
    var beforeTag= document.createElement("span");
    beforeTag.className = parentNode.className;
    beforeTag.innerHTML= tagText.before;
    var selectTag= document.createElement("span");
    selectTag.className = size;
    selectTag.innerHTML= tagText.selection;
    var afterTag= document.createElement("span");
    afterTag.className = parentNode.className;
    afterTag.innerHTML = tagText.after;
    parentNode.remove();
    selection.insertNode(afterTag);
    selection.insertNode(selectTag);
    selection.insertNode(beforeTag);


}

function getOuterRange(selection) {
    var rangeBefore = document.createRange();
    var rangeAfter = document.createRange();
    var r = selection.getRangeAt(0);

    rangeBefore.setStart(r.startContainer,0);
    rangeBefore.setEnd(r.startContainer,r.startOffset);

    rangeAfter.setStart(r.endContainer,r.endOffset);
    rangeAfter.setEnd(r.endContainer,r.endContainer.length);

    return {
        before: rangeBefore.toString(),
        selection: r.toString(),
        after: rangeAfter.toString()
    }
}
//returns the selection object.
function findSelection(){
    var userSelection;
    if (window.getSelection) {
        userSelection = window.getSelection();
    } // Mozilla Selection object.
    else if (document.selection){
        userSelection = document.selection.createRange();
    } //gets Microsoft Text Range, should be second b/c Opera has poor support for it.
    if (userSelection.text){
        return userSelection.text
    } //for Microsoft Objects.
    else {
        return userSelection
    } //For Mozilla Objects.
}



That works as expected. Im in a learning process, coming from C#, so this feels really hacky and i think i need to read a bit/lot more to get it to a usable solution. So, every advise and/or recommendation to JS Books would be a great help too

Where are the SPAN classes gone in this solution? It's also hard to know how to use the solution you proposed. Please create a [mre] - and edit/improve the question as well.

Once you have these two arrays:

character Array: ['F', 'o', 'o']
class Array: ['text-3xl', 'text-sm', 'text-3xl']

You can build the string:
<span class="text-3xl">F</span><span class="text-sm">o</span><span class="text-3xl">o</span>

You'll need to declare the class Array explicitly in your JavaScript.
But you can extract the character Array from your original <span>.

Working Example:


// EXTRACT ARRAY OF CHARACTERS FROM ORIGINAL SPAN
const originalSpan = document.querySelector('.original');
const originalSpanText = originalSpan.textContent;
const originalSpanTextArray = originalSpanText.split('');

// DECLARE LIST OF CLASSES
const classArray = ['text-3xl', 'text-sm', 'text-3xl'];

// BUILD NEW HTML
let newHTML = '';

originalSpanTextArray.forEach((character, i) => {
  newHTML += `<span class="${classArray[i]}">${character}</span>`;
});

// LOG NEW HTML
console.log(newHTML);
<span class="original text-3xl">Foo</span>




Further Reading:
The example above uses a backtick-demarcated template literal:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

